# pyspark dataframe after group by with applyInPandas has null value on one of the group by column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe,named "df_spark", I need to apply this function on each group of "amount" and "nature":

```
 def check(df):

   df_backup = df.sort_values('verified_time')
   df_backup['index'] = df_backup.index
   df_backup['IS_REPEATED'] = 0
   df_backup['nature_asc'] = 0
   df_backup['nature_desc'] = 0
   df_backup['nature_asc'] = df_backup.sort_values(['nature'],ascending=[True]).reset_index(drop=True)['nature']
   df_backup['nature_desc'] = df_backup.sort_values(['nature'],ascending=[False]).reset_index(drop=True)['nature']

   df.loc[df_backup['index'],'IS_REPEATED'] = [xor_two_list(x[0],x[1])
                                            for x in zip(df_backup['nature_asc'].values,df_backup['nature_desc'].values)]
   return df
```

This is "xor" function:

```
   def xor_two_list(first,second):
     if first!=second:
       return 1
     else:
       return 0
```

This function is for schema:

```
def get_schema(value):
   if value == 'trx':
     schema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), nullable=True),
                         StructField("time_stamp", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
                         StructField("account_id", StringType(), nullable=True),
                         StructField("IS_REPEATED", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
                         StructField("nature", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
                         StructField("amount", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
                         StructField("user_time", StringType(), nullable=True),
                         StructField("user_date", StringType(), nullable=True)])
                         
  return shcema
```

This is the line that works wrongly:

```
    df_new = df_spark.groupby(["account_id", "amount"]).applyInPandas(check,schema=get_schema('trx'))
```

When I receive "df_new", I run this command:

```
  df_new.select('account_id','amount','IS_REPEATED').where(col("amount").isNull()).show()
```

The "df_new" has **null** value for "amount" column when "IS_REPEATED" is "1". Even though, the first "df_spark" did not have any null value in "amount" column.

Would you please guide me what is wrong with the program?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: More helpful if you give a sample input data and desired output. A bit harder to follow through piece of code that is anyway not doing what its supposed to, creating sample input, solving the problem and then answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem was because of **get_schema(value)** did not create correct schema. In fact, there was problem about definition of "amount". Since, it had long number, I had to set its type **LongType()**.
The function was changed like this:

```
  def get_schema(value):
   if value == 'trx':
     schema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("time_stamp", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("account_id", StringType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("IS_REPEATED", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("nature", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("amount", LongType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("user_time", StringType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("user_date", StringType(), nullable=True)])
                     
  return shcema
```